# Can't seem to render a model loaded with Assimp

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, assimp

I'm currently learning OpenGL from the following [resource](https://learnopengl.com/).

I'm trying to implement most of the stuff in my own abstraction using several places as guidance.

I got to the [section](https://learnopengl.com/Model-Loading/Model) where you learn about model loading using the Assimp library.

When I try to draw the model **nothing but my background shows on screen**.

I've tried to debug the `ModelLoader` class to see if it's doing something wrong (although I mostly followed the tutorial, I've made some changes)
but it seems to me that it's doing its job.

I've also tried to make a basic fragment shader that just output white color to the screen instead of using mine lighting scene fragment shader that take into account all the materials and nothing still shows up.

I've implemented a `Camera` class using `lookAt` matrix and I update the `view` matrix sent to the vertex shader using it, so I can free roam incase the model was misplaces using the `model` matrix. Unfortunately this isn't the problem.

Here's the `ModelLoader` class implementation:

```
#include "ModelLoader.h"

static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Texture>> s_LoadedTextures;

static const std::unordered_map<aiTextureType, unsigned int> g_AiTextureTypeUnitMap
(
    {
        { aiTextureType::aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, 0 },
        { aiTextureType::aiTextureType_SPECULAR, 1 },
        { aiTextureType::aiTextureType_EMISSIVE, 2 },
        { aiTextureType::aiTextureType_AMBIENT, 3 },
        { aiTextureType::aiTextureType_HEIGHT, 4 },
    }
);

Model ModelLoader::Load(const std::string& path)
{
    Assimp::Importer importer;
    const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs | aiProcess_GenNormals);
    Model model(path);

    if (!scene || scene->mFlags & AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR ASSIMP " << importer.GetErrorString() << std::endl;
        return model;
    }

    ModelLoader::ProcessNode(model, scene->mRootNode, scene, path);

    return model;
}

void ModelLoader::ProcessNode(Model& model, aiNode* node, const aiScene* scene, const std::string& path)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++)
    {
        aiMesh* aiMesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
        Mesh mesh = ModelLoader::ProcessMesh(aiMesh, scene, path);
        model.AddMesh(mesh);
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
    {
        ModelLoader::ProcessNode(model, node->mChildren[i], scene, path);
    }
}

Mesh ModelLoader::ProcessMesh(aiMesh* aiMesh, const aiScene* scene, const std::string& path)
{
    std::vector<float> vertices;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < aiMesh->mNumVertices; i++)
    {
        vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mVertices[i].x);
        vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mVertices[i].y);
        vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mVertices[i].z);
        vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mNormals[i].x);
        vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mNormals[i].y);
        vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mNormals[i].z);
        if (aiMesh->HasTextureCoords(0))
        {
            vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x);
            vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y);
        }
        else
        {
            vertices.push_back(0.0f);
            vertices.push_back(0.0f);
            vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mTangents[i].x);
            vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mTangents[i].y);
            vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mTangents[i].z);
            vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mBitangents[i].x);
            vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mBitangents[i].y);
            vertices.push_back(aiMesh->mBitangents[i].z);
        }
    }

    std::vector<unsigned int> indices;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < aiMesh->mNumFaces; i++)
    {
        aiFace face = aiMesh->mFaces[i];
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++)
        {
            indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);
        }
    }

    std::shared_ptr<VertexArray> va = std::make_shared<VertexArray>();
    VertexBufferLayout layout;
    layout.Push({ GL_FLOAT, 3, sizeof(float) * 3, GL_FALSE });
    layout.Push({ GL_FLOAT, 3, sizeof(float) * 3, GL_FALSE });
    layout.Push({ GL_FLOAT, 2, sizeof(float) * 2, GL_FALSE });
    layout.Push({ GL_FLOAT, 3, sizeof(float) * 3, GL_FALSE });
    layout.Push({ GL_FLOAT, 3, sizeof(float) * 3, GL_FALSE });

    std::shared_ptr<VertexBuffer> vb = std::make_shared<VertexBuffer>(vertices.data(), sizeof(vertices.data()), layout);
    std::shared_ptr<IndexBuffer> ib = std::make_shared<IndexBuffer>(indices.data(), indices.size());

    va->SetVertexBuffer(vb);
    va->SetIndexBuffer(ib);

    std::shared_ptr<Material> material = std::make_shared<Material>();

    if (scene->HasMaterials())
    {
        aiMaterial* aiMaterial = scene->mMaterials[aiMesh->mMaterialIndex];
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Texture>> diffuseMaps = ModelLoader::LoadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial, aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, path);
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Texture>> specularMaps = ModelLoader::LoadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial, aiTextureType_SPECULAR, path);
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Texture>> emissiveMaps = ModelLoader::LoadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial, aiTextureType_EMISSIVE, path);
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Texture>> ambientMaps = ModelLoader::LoadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial, aiTextureType_AMBIENT, path);
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Texture>> heightMaps = ModelLoader::LoadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial, aiTextureType_HEIGHT, path);
        material->AddTextures(TextureType::DIFFUSE_MAP, diffuseMaps);
        material->AddTextures(TextureType::SPECULAR_MAP, specularMaps);
        material->AddTextures(TextureType::EMISSIVE_MAP, emissiveMaps);
        material->AddTextures(TextureType::AMBIENT_MAP, ambientMaps);
        material->AddTextures(TextureType::HEIGHT_MAP, heightMaps);
        material->SetShininess(32.0f);
    }

    return Mesh(va, material);
}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Texture>> ModelLoader::LoadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial* material, aiTextureType type, const std::string& path)
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Texture>> textures;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < material->GetTextureCount(type); i++)
    {
        aiString name;
        material->GetTexture(type, i, &name);
        std::string texturePath = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('/')) + '/' + name.C_Str();
        if (s_LoadedTextures.find(texturePath) == s_LoadedTextures.end())
        {
            std::shared_ptr<Texture> texture = std::make_shared<Texture>(texturePath, g_AiTextureTypeUnitMap.at(type));
            textures.push_back(texture);
            s_LoadedTextures.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Texture>>::value_type(texturePath, texture));
        }
    }
    return textures;
}
```

The `LoaderModel` class assumes the model and its textures are sitting together in the same directory.

Here's the `Mesh` class:

```
#include "Mesh.h"

#include "OGL.h"

#include "uniform/Uniform1i.cpp"
#include "uniform/Uniform1f.cpp"

Mesh::Mesh(std::shared_ptr<VertexArray>& va, std::shared_ptr<Material>& material)
    : m_VertexArray(va), m_Material(material)
{
}


void Mesh::Draw(Shader& shader)
{
    std::unordered_map<TextureType, std::string> textureTypeNameMap
    (
        {
            {TextureType::DIFFUSE_MAP, "diffuse"},
            {TextureType::SPECULAR_MAP, "specular"},
            {TextureType::EMISSIVE_MAP, "emissive"},
        }
    );

    for (auto& it : textureTypeNameMap) {
        const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Texture>>& textures = m_Material->GetTextures(it.first);
        for (const auto& texture : textures)
        {
            texture->Bind();
            Uniform1i textureUniform("u_Material." + textureTypeNameMap[it.first]);
            textureUniform.SetValues({ (int)texture->GetUnit() });
            shader.SetUniform(textureUniform);
        }
    }

    Uniform1f shininessUniform("u_Material.shininess");
    shininessUniform.SetValues({ m_Material->GetShininess() });
    shader.SetUniform(shininessUniform);

    if (m_VertexArray->GetIndexBuffer()->GetCount())
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
    else
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_VertexArray->GetVertexBuffer()->GetSize());
}
```

The `Model` class just holds `std::vector<Mesh>` of meshes and call `mesh.Draw()` for each mesh.

`Texure` class:

```
#include "Texture.h"
#include "stb_image/stb_image.h"

Texture::Texture(const std::string& path, unsigned int unit)
    : m_Path(path), m_Unit(unit)
{
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    m_Buffer = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &m_Width, &m_Height, &m_channels, 0);

    GLenum format;
    if (m_channels == 1)
        format = GL_RED;
    else if (m_channels == 3)
        format = GL_RGB;
    else if (m_channels == 4)
        format = GL_RGBA;

    GLCALL(glGenTextures(1, &m_RendererID));
    GLCALL(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit));
    GLCALL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID));
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST));
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT));
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT));
    GLCALL(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, m_Width, m_Height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_Buffer));
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLCALL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));

    if (m_Buffer)
        stbi_image_free(m_Buffer);
    std::cout << "Texture CREATED: " << m_RendererID << ", " << m_Path << std::endl;
}

Texture::~Texture()
{
    std::cout << "Texture DELETED: " << m_RendererID << ", " << m_Path << std::endl;
    GLCALL(glDeleteTextures(1, &m_RendererID));
}

void Texture::Bind() const
{
    GLCALL(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + m_Unit));
    GLCALL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID));
}

void Texture::Unbind() const
{
    GLCALL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
}

void Texture::Filter(unsigned int filter, unsigned int mode) const
{
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, filter, mode));
}

void Texture::Wrap(unsigned int wrap, unsigned int mode) const
{
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, wrap, mode));
}
```

`App.cpp` (only the relevant things):

```
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    {
        /* Make the window's context current */
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebufferSizeCallback);

        glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouseCallback);
        glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouseButtonCallback);

        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        Shader shader1;
        shader1.Attach(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "res/shaders/lightning_scene_vs.shader");
        shader1.Attach(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "res/shaders/lightning_scene_fs.shader");
        shader1.Link();
        shader1.Bind();

        Model nanosuit = ModelLoader::Load("res/models/nanosuit/nanosuit.obj");


        /* Loop until the user closes the window */
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {
            Time::Update();
            processInput(window);

            glClearColor(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f, 1.0f);
            renderer.Clear();

            float timeValue = glfwGetTime();

            float radius = 2.0f;
            pointLightPos = glm::vec3(cos(timeValue) * radius, 1.0f, sin(timeValue) * radius);

            glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)SCREEN_WIDTH / (float)SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
            UniformMat4f projectionUniform("u_Projection");
            projectionUniform.SetValues(projection);

            glm::mat4 view = camera.GetView();
            UniformMat4f viewUniform("u_View");
            viewUniform.SetValues(view);

            Uniform3f viewPosUniform("u_ViewPos");
            viewPosUniform.SetValues({ camera.GetEye().x, camera.GetEye().y, camera.GetEye().z });

            spotLightPositionUniform.SetValues({ camera.GetEye().x, camera.GetEye().y, camera.GetEye().z });
            shader1.SetUniform(spotLightPositionUniform);

            spotLightDirectionUniform.SetValues({ camera.GetForward().x, camera.GetForward().y, camera.GetForward().z });
            shader1.SetUniform(spotLightDirectionUniform);

            glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
            model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.75f, 0.0f));
            model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f));
            UniformMat4f modelUniform("u_Model");
            modelUniform.SetValues(model);

            pointLightPositionUniform.SetValues({ pointLightPos.x, pointLightPos.y, pointLightPos.z });

            shader1.SetUniform(projectionUniform);
            shader1.SetUniform(viewUniform);
            shader1.SetUniform(modelUniform);
            shader1.SetUniform(pointLightPositionUniform);
            shader1.SetUniform(viewPosUniform);
            renderer.Draw(nanosuit, shader1);

            glfwPollEvents();
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        }
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a mistake while calculating the size of the vertices vector passed to the `constructor` of `VertexBuffer` later passed to `glBufferData`. I used `sizeof(vertices.data())` instead of `vertices.size() * sizeof(float)` since the first argument will return the size of a pointer on the machine.